# Joda time local zone to utc conversion

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying gmt asia/kolkata timemillis convert to utc timemillis but it returns same value. Environment time is asia/kolkata

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you provide a [mcve] that shows what you're trying at the moment? It's quite confusing, particularly when you refer to "gmt asia/kolkata timemillis". (Additionally, if you can *possibly* use `java.time` instead of JodaTime, I'd recommend that. At least you're not using java.util though...)

Comment: If you can, you should switch to the new Java Date and Time API, available in the `java.time` package. Joda Time is supplanted by this API.

Comment: dateTimeMillis=1550651407474// timezone asia/kolkata 
        final DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID(zoneId);
        final DateTime localZoneDateTime = new DateTime(dateTimeMillis);
        final DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(localZoneDateTime).withZone(zone);
        long utc= dateTime.getMillis();
after utc zone give 1550651407474 this value

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54782121/edit) and add new information there so we have everything in one place and so that your code is readable (when you format it as code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The epoch is time zone independent. So you should get the same number of milliseconds since the epoch back no matter which time zone you convert to.

So the result you got is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as this

```
     Instant date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1549362600000l);
     LocalDateTime utc = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

You need not to use Joda time api has moved to java 1.8 has implemented the same you can use above same from **java.time** package